# Is there a way to generate synthetic patient data and then expose it through fhir schema?

Tags: hl7-fhir

Currently trying to build a nodejs based server to achieve this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Stackoverflow is a coding community, your question is not coding related and doesn't describe a specific coding problem.

Comment: sorry about that, thanks for the help anyways

Answer (score 4):

You want to check out the synthea project: https://synthetichealth.github.io/synthea/